# How to get a float value even if both the inputs are integers

Tags: jmeter

I am running a graphQL request in which 'paymentAmount' is one of the variables:

```
"paymentAmount": "${__V(price_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}"
```

In this case sum of the different prices could be an integer or a float value but the issue is that the system accepts only float so irrespective of the result of the sum I need to pass a float value that is to say that if the result of sum is 72 then I need to pass 72.00 and if the result of sum is 72.15 then I need to pass 72.15.
How to handle this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go for [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to convert the integers into doubles with trailing zeroes, something like:

```
${__groovy(new java.text.DecimalFormat('#.00').format(vars.get('price_' + ((vars.get('__jm__ForEach Controller__idx') as int) + 1)) as double),)}
```

[image]